# Not getting relative path in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

i am unable to get the Relative path in pycharm

tried all the ways but was unable to succeed

This Test1.py is present in Pages/ folder

[image: Folder Structure]

iam trying the code

```
import os

import xlrd



index = 0
#wb = xlrd.open_workbook(f"./data/search_flights_input_data.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(f".//data//search_flights_input_data.xlsx")

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(index)
```

but getting the error as

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/User/Downloads/Selenium-Python-Example-main/Selenium-Python-Example-main/pages/test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Downloads/Selenium-Python-Example-main/Selenium-Python-Example-main/pages/test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(f".//data//search_flights_input_data.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './/data//search_flights_input_data.xlsx'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try this: `xlrd.open_workbook(f"./search_flights_input_data.xlsx")`

Comment: On run configurations you can set the initial path. And for better debugging: `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Thanks for reply @gajendragarg, tried your code got this error " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './search_flights_input_data.xlsx'"

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, when i print "print(os.getcwd())" getting output as   C:\Users\User\Downloads\Selenium-Python-Example-main\Selenium-Python-Example-main\pages

Comment: so `../` instead of `./` ?

Comment: @Learner Understood. Try this: `xlrd.open_workbook(f"../data/search_flights_input_data.xlsx")`

Comment: Thank you to both of you, it worked and so by understanding .. means to point to the directory